# Find repeated count from input data stream... 

Tags: c#

I have tried several time but couldn’t find the way to solve my problem. Here my txt file shown in below.

```
695
748
555
695
748
852
639
748
```

I put the for loop to read the data and put them in to array. So now I want to filter repeat numbers from the input txt data. How can I have a count of repeated data.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 0;
        int count = 0;
        String[] line = File.ReadAllLines("C:/num.txt");
        int n = line.Length;
        String[] res = new String[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {

            res[i] = line[i].Substring(x,x+8);
                Console.WriteLine(res[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Somehow you have to keep track of things you have seen before.

One way to do that is to place the numbers in a list the first time you see them.  If a given number is already in the list, filter it out on the latter occurrences.

Here's an example with the list.  Note that your code to fetch a substring of the input crashes.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 0;
    int count = 0;
    String[] line = new string[] { "123", "456", "123" }; //File.ReadAllLines("C:/num.txt");
    int n = line.Length;
    String[] res = new String[n];
    List<string> observedValues = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        string consider = line[i]; // This code crashes: .Substring(x, x + 8);
        if (!observedValues.Contains(consider))
        {
            observedValues.Add(consider);
            res[i] = consider;
            Console.WriteLine(res[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Skipped value: " + consider + " on line " + i);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Another method is to pre-sort the input so that duplicates are adjacent.

Example:

(Note, you may want to remove white space in the input prior to sorting.  Leading white space will break this code).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 0;
    int count = 0;
    String[] line = new string[] { "123", "456", "123" }; //File.ReadAllLines("C:/num.txt");
    int n = line.Length;
    String[] res = new String[n];
    string previous = null;
    Array.Sort(line); // Ensures that equal values are adjacent
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        string consider = line[i].Trim(); // Note leading whitespace will break this.
        if (consider != previous)
        {
            previous = consider;
            res[i] = consider;
            Console.WriteLine(res[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Skipped value: " + consider + " on line " + i);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: @Chamal: Posted examples that are as close to your existing code as reasonable.

Comment: @Chamal: Your code doesn't actually increase the 'count' variable.  You would want to do that in the case where you output a new number.

Answer (score 2):

You use `GroupBy()`

```
var result = res.GroupBy(x => x);
foreach(var g in result)
{
      Console.WriteLine(g.Key + " count: " + g.Count());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> > > So now I want to filter repeat numbers from the input txt data.

if all you need is filter out duplicates you can use this:

```
String[] line = File.ReadAllLines("C:/num.txt");
var filteredLines = line.Distinct();

foreach (var item in filteredLines)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```